# How to choose different colors for different Android APIs for a specific property?

Tags: android, html, css

Say I have this colorPrimaryDark set for API > 23:

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="23">#FFFFFF</color>
```

How can I set it to black for older APIs?

Comment: Android works with several API-driven resourse folders. Just like values, strings and evertything else, there is a values-vX for every API that you are willing to work with.

Comment: Just found out from the answer :> Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably set a color without the tools:targetApi that will be used for any other android api.
I think that its a better approach to create a colors.xml inside a folder dedicated to the API you want, like if you want your color to be used in every api 16 target, you can create a folder named values-v16 inside your res folder and create a new colors.xml inside it.